# Print each elements of array list in new line in logcat in android

Tags: android

In my app I have `ArrayList` which contains application package names.I want to print each elements of `ArrayList` in a new line in logcat like this:

com.android.mms

com.android.contacts

com.whatsapp

Like this in Log cat.

How can I do that.

Comment: In a loop. `Log.i("tag", "text");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can print all names from array list, this way:

```
private final String TAG = "DEBUG_TAG";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    List<String> nameList = new ArrayList<>();

    //populate nameList
    ...

    for(String name : nameList)
        Log.d(TAG, name);
}
```

Comment: @Sandeep It it helped, you can up vote and accept this answer :-)

Comment: Actually this code is dangerous, for in the Release version, ProGuard will strip the Log code, and you may stay with an non-closed loop. Put the Log code in curly brackets, so after ProGuard you will have empty loop. That is also not best.